# Felicity inverter TVS diode

Tags: diodes, identification

I have a Felicity solar inverter machine that went bad due to rain water penetration from the roof. While replacing the bad components I found this SMD diode with a code from which I couldn’t decipher the voltage or code for replacement.

I could only see letters like LB MHHR DGP. I wouldn’t mind if anyone can help with equivalent diode or data sheet for checking TVS diode value. Dimensions: 7mm x 8mm.

Comment: Hey. Welcome here. Please don't randomly sprinkle your question with tags, I had to remove all of the non-fitting ones.

Comment: A photo could help; please try to attach one.